# What does the end part of this declaration do?

Tags: javascript

I've just been sent this and am unsure about the last part of this variable declaration:

`var u = (document.getElementById('myaccount').className.match(/loggedin/)) ? 'true' : 'false';`

From what I can see this is performing a pattern match for the string "loggedin" but what does the end `? 'true' : 'false';` part do?

I've not seen anything like this before so am unsure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the ternary operator, it can be though of like this:

```
result = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
```

Which is just shorthand for:

```
if(condition == true) {

    result = value_if_true;

} else {

    result = value_if_false;

}
```

The `condition` part can be a variable, function or expression, so the following are all valid:

```
result = myVariable ? value if true : value if false;

result = myFunction() ? value if true : value if false;

result = (myVariable > 10) ? value if true : value if false;
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this. very neat way of shortening the `if`!

Comment: I totally agree with this, but would like to add just for fun that the ?: construction is also sometimes called the Elvis operator. Look at the characters and you see why :-)

Answer (score 1):

inline if

```
condition_check ? result if true : result if false
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a ternary if/else statement.

If the className.match(/logged/) evaluates to true then it returns true, else false.

A classier way of writing

```
var u;
if(document.getElementById('myaccount').className.match(/loggedin/)) {
    u = true;
} else {
    u = false;
}
return u;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called a ternary if statement.

If your **myaccount** element has a class '**loggedin**', variable u will be set to **TRUE**.  Otherwise it will be set to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

That is another way to declare if statements

```
<condition> ? <return if condition is true> : <return if condition is false>
```

It's the same as this

```
var u;
if (document.getElementById('myaccount').className.match(/loggedin/)){
   u = 'true'; 
} else {
   u = 'false';
}
```